# Cross domain XHR works strange

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, client-side

I've been stacked with issue which I can't solve
for about month. You can look at the example page here: http://www.7ya.ru/travel/tours/

So, the problem is that little green form is our widget which uses cross-domain XHR and
some people have problem with it. XHR request fails. There is no request exactly. Inspector 
just says "canceled". This problem occures in FF, Opera and Chrome on OSX and Win.

BUT! If you'll try to clean cache (for example in Chrome):

[image: checkboxes in chrome private data controll]

you will see that the widget is starts to work like a charm.
Also if you'll try to clean only a cache it wont work.

So, is anybody has ideas about which data may affect XHR requests in most browsers on two different platforms?

**P.S.** I've been trying to use "vanilla" XHR and jQuery version but it works same.

**P.S.S.** Bit of code (CoffeeScript):

1. lt_jq – local jQuery version ($.noConflict())
2. @inspect - JSON.stringify() with some additional params for formatting

---

```
request = lt_jq.ajax({
    url       : method,
    dataType  : "json",
    data      : params,
    xhrFields : withCredentials:true
})

request.done (data)->
    @request_id = (data.request_id || null)
    callback?(data)

request.fail =>
    console.log "Request failed [#{method}], #{@inspect(params)}"
```

**QUESTION CLOSED, DETAILS IN COMMENTS**

Comment: CORS is fully supported in FF, Opera, Chrome and IE10. WebSocket too but it's really strange solution. I suppose that functionality of this widget is not in WebSocket competence. Widget don't requires "live" ui. It just sends the data to the server and receives JSON. Nothing else.

Comment: And of course widget sends the data on demand.

Comment: For backend we use RoR (Unicorn, NGINX, RoR).

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? If so, what was it?

Comment: Not yet. No enough time. I will write if there will be some new information. I suppose that i'll finish on Monday-Tuesday.

Comment: We've get nothing with it so I switched whole widget to jsonp instead of xhr. CORS looks very unstable now.

Answer (score 0):

Does the network you're in use a caching proxy, or from the sound of it, do you have an antivirus or some sort of filter on the network which filters the requests through?

It sounds like the files are being cached without the correct headers, so the CORS headers are being cut off...

The easiest way I suggest you check this:
USING CHROME:

1. Clear your cache, open the dev tools, and watch the request when it
   **does** work. Make sure you have the CORS headers in the request and response headers.
2. Now that you have the file in your cache, reload your page. Check that it's not working.
3. Now that it doesn't work, go to chrome://view-http-cache/ to view the individual cache
   entries, and look for that file's request. Open it.
4. Check if the cached file has the CORS headers on it.

If it doesn't... make sure the proxy/antivirus doesn't cut off the CORS headers in your network, or try a different solution

Comment: No antivirus, no firewall etc. I'm not sure about proxy. I suppose that it's more depends on computer which is in use. Because on my laptop (no matter which network I use) everything works fine. But for example on my colleague's laptop it fails. Thanks for the hint about individual cache, i'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: So if it's cache how can I clean it remotely on customers computers?

Comment: if it's cache and the first request fails, you need a fallback request:
1. Request the file again but adding a pragma: no-cache header to the request
2. Request the file again as JSONP

If you use jquery, you can add this to your header:
beforeSend: function (xhr)
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            }
Source: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/2918/how-to-set-a-request-header-in-a-jquery-ajax-call.aspx

If you add this header, with CORS, you might need to take care of the 'preflight' as this is considered 'OPTIONS': http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: Thanks for your hints but it doesn't work for me. So now we use jsonp instead of xhr.